# How to re-install system-settings?

Tags: system-settings

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04
I tried to install `im-switch`, but it uninstalled `im-config` and `language support`, making system setting very difficult, my system-setting page becomes this

[image: Settings windows]

And I've re-installed `Language Support` and `im-config` using `apt-get`, but other settings does not come back.

How can I turn it into previous setting page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reinstalling `unity-control-center` should fix the problem.

Reinstall it by executing following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Comment: wooah fixed!!!....i couldn't set system proxy via gui again. Thanks

Comment: not working for me.... only three icons visible: `Language, Printers and Software & Updates`

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (and later?), one should use `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center`

Comment: System Settings does not open in my Ubuntu system. But when I try to install gnome-control-center, it says, its already the newest version. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall `'Settings'` by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

Now `'Settings'` appears in `'Show Applications'` again.

or you can also open it by typing below command

```
gnome-control-center
```